# How can I pass a model to my main view template without code duplication in every controller?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.4

In my main view template I want to display dynamic data (from database), for example the navigation items for a website.

When I add the model to the template as a parameter, every view that uses my main template is required to provide the model for the main template. Consequently, every action in every controller first needs to fetch the navigation model for the main template.

This approach would lead to code duplication and violation of the single responsibility principle, because every action needs to know how to retrieve the main template model. Is there a way to provide the described functionality without code duplication in an isolated manner, while keeping the code testable?

**Example**

The following can be used to mock the model and service classes:

```
package services

import scala.concurrent.Future

case class HeaderItem(title: String, url: String)
case class User(name: String, email: String)

class HeaderItemService {
  val all: Future[Seq[HeaderItem]] = Future.successful(HeaderItem("Home", "/") :: Nil)
}

class UserService {
  val all: Future[Seq[User]] = Future.successful(User("Test", "test@test") :: Nil)
}
```

The main view template displays the header items:

```
@import services.HeaderItem
@(headerItems: Seq[HeaderItem])(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <ul>
            @for(item <- headerItems) {
                <li>@item.title</li>
            }
            </ul>
        </div>
        @content
    </body>
</html>
```

Child views display views specific data (users) and must pass main-template specific data to the template:

```
@import services.HeaderItem
@import services.User
@(headerItems: Seq[HeaderItem], users: Seq[User])

@main(headerItems) {
    <ul>
        @for(user <- users) {
            <li>@user.name</li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

And this is the controller that has to care about as well navigation items as well as users:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._

import play.api.mvc._
import services.{HeaderItemService, UserService}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(headerItemService: HeaderItemService, userService: UserService) extends Controller {
  def index = Action.async {
    for {
      headerItems <- headerItemService.all
      users <- userService.all
    } yield Ok(views.html.index(headerItems, users))
  }
}
```

**First tries**

In ASP MVC the problem could be approached by rendering actions inside views using the Html.RenderAction method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee839451(v=vs.100).aspx). As far as I know a similar approach is not possible with the play framework (2.4).

Comment: You could use javascript in main template that would fetch header items from separate endpoint

Comment: @Lukasz: With javascript I could indeed build a solution similar to the ASP RenderAction-approach, but also it would bring in new dependencies and make the views less readable. I would prefer a solution based on Scala only.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to reorganize the code to reduce duplication. The thing to keep in mind is that a template is just a function from some specified parameters to `Html`. With that in mind, you can organize your controller like this:

```
@Singleton 
class Renderer @Inject() (headerItemService: HeaderItemService) {
  // wrap some content html with a layout with a menu
  private def renderWithMenu (content: Html): Future[Html] = {
    for {
      headerItems <- headerItemService.all
    } yield views.html.layoutWithMenu(headerItems, content)
  }
}

@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(userService: UserService, renderer: Renderer) extends Controller with ControllerOps {
  def index = Action.async {
    for {
      users <- userService.all
      // views.html.index now only contains the "content" html
      rendered <- renderer.renderWithMenu(views.html.index(users))
    } yield Ok(rendered)
  }
}
```

Although this code is still responsible for "triggering" the rendering of a menu, the responsibility for obtaining the items and producing the `Html` has been moved to a trait where it can be re-used.

Regarding `Action` composition, I think it is a bit of overkill for template UI stuff. I usually reserve that for authentication or other code that performs more complex logic (custom request object, modify params, authorization, etc).

Comment: Alvaro, thank you for your response, this is pretty much what I was looking for, as it separates the code of loading the headers from all actions. Compared to the approach of using action composition, I prefer this solution because I do not have to pass the headers through the views.

Nonetheless, one last thing bugs me: I still need to inject the HeaderItemService into any controller that will use the ControllerOps trait. Is there any way to reduce the coupling by moving the dependency out of the controllers? I guess I could make the trait an abstract class, but I would prefer another way.

Comment: @Felix I updated the code. Not sure if that's what you're referring to by abstract class. If so, what is the problem with it? At the end of the day, the `index` method needs to be able to render a "full" page. It makes sense for it to depend on another component for help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom action using function composition.

Note that `getHeadersFromDB` is a db call which should return immediately if not user has to wait too long. Optimize it or use some cache layer.

```
def withHeadersAction(f: Headers => Request[AnyContent] => Future[Result]) = { 
   Action.async { req => 
        getHeadersFromDB.map { headers => 
          f(headers)(req)
        }.recover { case th => Ok(s"oops error occurred ${th.getMessage}")}
    }
}
```

*How to use this custom Action*

```
ApplicationController @Inject() () extends Controller {

   def foo = withHeadersAction { implicit headers => req =>
      Ok(views.html.something) //headers is implicitly passed to the view
   }

}
```

*Note that `implicit` parameters can be used to get rid of passing params explicitly*

something.scala.html

```
@(implicit headers: List[Headers]) 
@main("something") {
  //doSomething()
}
```

**Other way**

*Only create content in the action and everything will be taken care by withHeadersAction internally for you*

define view like this `views.html.something(headers)(content)`

```
 def withHeadersAction(f: Request[AnyContent] => Future[Html]) = { 
       Action.async { req => 
            getHeadersFromDB.flatMap { headers => 
              f(req).map { content => Ok(views.html.something(headers)(content)}
            }.recover { case th => Ok(s"oops error occurred ${th.getMessage}")}
        }
    }

ApplicationController @Inject() () extends Controller {

       def bar = withHeadersAction { req =>
          Future.successful(views.html.someContent())
       }

    }
```

Comment: This approach would encapsulate the code to load the headers into a separate function, which is nice. But still, I would need to pass the header-items into any view that uses the main view, so I would prefer the approach of using a trait as Alvaro proposed.

Comment: @Felix .. you can use `implicit` params to get rid of passing headers explicitly.

Comment: Thank you pamu, indeed this would work as requested. I still prefer the approach of rendering the main template separately (see Alvaro's answer) because it hides the parameters to the main class even better. Imagine I would have to change the main-view-model's type or add one, with the solution of using implicits I would need to change every action. When encapsulate the rendering of the main-template into a separate function I can do pass in whatever I need.

Comment: That looks nice! Would it also be possible to pass the Status from the controller to the action? Further more the HeaderItemService needs to be injected into the withHeadersAction somehow. For example by wrapping withHeadersAction in a class MainAction which has the service as a constructor dependency. The controller could then be injected with MainAction, where withHeadersAction could be renamed to apply to leave out the method name.

Answer (score 0):

Based on pamu's approach I formulated a similar approach using a custom action builder:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._

import play.api.mvc.{BodyParser, _}
import play.twirl.api.Html
import services.{HeaderItemService, UserService}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

class MainAction @Inject()(headerItemService: HeaderItemService) extends Results {
  def apply(block: Request[AnyContent] => (Status, Future[Html])) = Action.async { request =>
    execute(request, block)
  }

  def apply[A](bodyParser: BodyParser[A])(block: Request[A] => (Status, Future[Html])) = Action.async(bodyParser) { request =>
    execute(request, block)
  }

  def execute[A](request: Request[A], block: Request[A] => (Status, Future[Html])) = {
    val (status, futureContent) = block(request)
    for {
      content <- futureContent
      headerItems <- headerItemService.all
    } yield status(views.html.main(headerItems)(content))
  }
}

@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(mainAction: MainAction, userService: UserService) extends Controller {
  def index = mainAction { request =>
    val content = userService.all.map(users => views.html.index(users))
    (mainAction.Ok, content)
  }
}
```

This approach includes the injection of dependencies into a separate class that is responsible for rendering the main view template, as well as the possibility to pass the status from the custom actions that render the sub-views.